# Manage local settings (like query string) between developers in ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, settings

We develop ASP.NET MVC application and using differnt databases to run code locally.

Which is a proper way to configure application to allow us using our own local settings and database bindings without hurting each others?

Comment: Ignore the settings files in source control?

Comment: Than it should not be webconfig?

Comment: A hack - you could add a post-build step to replace the web.config file from a separate directory, if you can ensure each developer keeps a copy of their personal web.config in that location.

Comment: Put it in your web.config. Then have a test.web.config and a prod.web.config which you switch to when releasing to test/production environments.